# Using an ejb Timer in a @SessionScoped

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, ejb-3.1

I'm working on a thesis which includes a Java EE 6 project. I need to set up an example project about a restaurant service which needs to deliver food within one hour (from the call). The project will use CDI Api and, although it might fit with a BPM framework, I'd need to use just plain Java EE 6 Api.

I've been thinking about several viable choices, but the only one that fits with my requirements is backing the User request with a @SessionScoped Bean. Then from there start an EJB timer which will timeout in our hour (late delivery), unless it is cancelled by the user (delivery in time).

My concern is: can I associate a 1:1 relationship between a @SessionScoped Bean and an EJB Timer ? in other words, the EJB timer should be associated just with the User, which needs to be notified is the timer expired.
Can you suggest me if I'm on a good track or should I rethink over the architecture ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question about the 1:1 mapping, the spec says the following:

> For automatically created timers, the timeout method may be a method that is annotated with the Schedule annotation. Timers can be created for stateless session beans, singleton session beans, message-driven beans, and 2.1 entity beans[94]. Timers cannot be created for stateful session beans[95] ...

Furthermore, "@SessionScoped" transforms your POJO into an CDI managed bean and the Timer service is an EJB feature.

However, assuming you have access to a database I would suggest the following solution:
As soon as a customer orders something, create an entry in the database, including a 'created' timestamp.
Configure a Scheduler/Timer that polls this table each minute to verify (by checking the timestamp column) if any user needs to get informed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need an implementation of design pattern Observer

CDI offer this service by using @Observes, have a look at this example http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_ee_6_observer_with

fire an event with your customer data and you can call an @asynchronous service which do your processing after one hour, in case of losing data or an exception happens try to persist your unsuccessful operations in database

the @Schedule service could be used to scan for all unsuccessful operations and try to do your processing again

alternatively .. could you try to see what a JMS solution offers too

hope I did understand..